# Не пойму, в чем причина ошибок

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добрый день, проект делал не я, но пришлось запускать мне. После запуска все вроде работает, но смущают ошибки. JDK установлен. Прошу помочь разобраться, как их устранить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IDEA подсказывает вам, что JDK не настроен для проекта - нажмите <kbd>Setup JDK</kbd> и выберите нужный JDK.

Comment: Пробовал, к сожалению не помогло

Comment: После того как выбрали, IDEA все еще предлагала снова указать ее?

Comment: Да, выбрал из списка JDK нажал ОК. Скопировал этот проект на другую машину, там не ругается